# Try/Except not running properly when opening files

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I am trying to open a file with this Try/Except block but it is going straight to Except and not opening the file.

I've tried opening multiple different files but they are going directly to not being able to open.

```
import string

fname = input('Enter a file name: ')

try:
    fhand = open(fname)
except:
    print('File cannot be opened:', fname)
    exit()

counts = dict()
L_N=0
for line in fhand:
    line= line.rstrip()
    line = line.translate(line.maketrans(' ', ' ',string.punctuation))
    line = line.lower()
    words = line.split()
    L_N+=1
    for word in words:
        if word not in counts:
            counts[word]= [L_N]
        else:
            if L_N not in counts[word]:
                counts[word].append(L_N)
for h in range(len(counts)):
    print(counts)
out_file = open('word_index.txt', 'w')
out_file.write('Text file being analyzed is: '+str(fname)+ '\n\n')
out.file_close()
```

I would like the output to read a specific file and count the created dictionary

Comment: You are opening in readmode, so it looks for the file in the current directory with this name, since there is no such file you get an exception

Comment: Are you sure you are giving the full file path? Unless you provide that, python cannot fine the file and therefor cannot open it

Comment: `out.file_close()`  isn't correct. should be `out_file.close()`

Answer (score 1):

1. make sure you are inputting quotes for your filename ("myfile.txt") if using python 2.7. if python3, quotes are not required.
2. make sure your input is using absolute path to the file, or make sure the file exists in the same place you are running the python program.

for example, 
if your program and current working directory is in ~/code/
and you enter: 'myfile.txt', 'myfile.txt' must exist in ~/code/

however, its best you provide the absolute path to your input file such as

```
/home/user/myfile.txt
```

then your script will work 100% of the time, no matter what directory you call your script from.